# I have button in my datatable and I want to pass the row values to a modal

Tags: jquery, html

How do I get my button to open a modal and pass the card_no to that modal?

```
<tr>
 <td><? =$row['Card_no'] ?> <td>
<td><input type="button" /> </td>

</tr>
```

Comment: Are you using twitter-bootstrap modal?

Comment: That's all code you have ?

Comment: yeah I'm using twitter-bootsrap modal